# Mutt client can't sign in to mail server with decrypted passphrase

Tags: login, password, mutt

Recently changed my mail login password to a passphrase.

*.muttrc* is set to call `gpg` to decrypt the file containing the password then `awk` the content into temp file and pass it to `mutt` (then delete the decrypted tmp file).
The method worked perfectly with a single password. After having changed the password into a space separated phrase `mutt` now stops at the second word of the phrase with the error message:

```
Error in ~/.muttrc, line 2: Word2: unknown variable
```

where *Word2* is the second word of the actual passphrase

*.muttrc* is:

```
set my_tmpsecret=`gpg -o ~/.crypt/.tmp -d ~/.crypt/.passwd.gpg`
set my_gpass=`awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' ~/.crypt/.tmp`
set my_del=`rm -f ~/.crypt/.tmp`

set imap_user="somebody@gmail.com"
set imap_pass=$my_gpass
set folder="imaps://somebody@imap.gmail.com:993/"
set spoolfile="+INBOX"
set postponed="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set record="+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set trash ="+[Gmail]/Trash"
mailboxes       = +INBOX 

set smtp_url = "smtp://somebody@smtp.gmail.com:587"  
set smtp_pass=$my_gpass
set record=""
set from="somebody@gmail.com"
set realname="Some Body"

set smart_wrap = yes
set sort = 'threads'
set sort_aux = 'last-date-received'
set imap_check_subscribed

#ignore "Authentication-Results:"
ignore "DomainKey-Signature:"
ignore "DKIM-Signature:"
hdr_order Date From To Cc

set date_format="%y-%m-%d %T"
set index_format="%2C | %Z [%d] %-30.30F (%-4.4c) %s"
set editor='vim + -c "set textwidth=72" -c "set wrap" -c "set nocp" -c "?^$"'
set header_cache = ~/.cache/mutt

#set message_cachedir = "~/.cache/mutt"
unset imap_passive
set imap_keepalive = 300
set mail_check = 120
```

The same if `$1,$2,...,$n` is replaced by `$0`

Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out what your `.muttrc` contains. Please write a `.muttrc` that reproduces the problem and post it and the error message *exactly*. If that would reveal your password, change it to a dummy password but post the exact file that leads to the exact error message.

Comment: I changed the code in the original post. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.muttrc` file is not a shell script, it's a configuration file that allows you to set particular variable that Mutt knows about.

Mutt does not have a configuration variable called `passwd`, so it complains when you try to set it. Variables prefixed by `my_` are ok though.

Rather than going through a temporary variable (which doesn't work), set `imap_pass` directly to the value.

---

After update to question:

Your problem stems from your password being multiple space-separate words.

In the Mutt configuration you can not have

```
set my_variable=some words
```

without proper quoting,

```
set my_variable="some words"
```

This means that your issue will be solved through

```
set my_gpass="`awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' ~/.crypt/.tmp`"
```

Comment: It has never complained when I was using a traditional, single unit password only after I (had to) change it to a space separated passphrase

Comment: @xatt Try with `set passwd="hello"` and you will get the same error. You are only allowed to set variables that Mutt knows about.

Comment: The exact (real) name of the variable is `my_gpass`. I assume mutt knows about it because I have been using it for years with a password like "hello".

Comment: Bingo! Now it works as a Swiss watch. Thanks a lot @Kusalananda